# How to convert Google Charts Data Table into python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I'm using the [Google Visualization Library for python](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-python) (gviz) to generate chart objects. This works great for generating JSON that can be read by the Google Charts using the `DataTable.ToJSon` method. What I'm trying to do now, however, is add multiple Google Chart data tables to one JSON dictionary. In other words, what I'm making now is this:

```
Chart_Data = JSON_Chart_Data_1
```

and what I want to make is this:

```
Chart_Data = {'Chart_1' : JSON_Chart_Data_1,
              'Chart_2' : JSON_Chart_Data_2,}
```

Where Chart_Data is converted into a JSON string in both cases.

I'm pretty sure I can do this by converting the JSON string from gviz *back* into a python dictionary, compile the strings in a container dictionary as necessary, and then convert that container dictionary back into JSON, but that doesn't seem like a very elegant way to do it. Is there a better way? What I'm picturing is a `.ToPythonObject` method equivalent to `.ToJSon`, but there doesn't appear to be one in the library.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing my original, inelegant, solution to the problem with this function:

```
def CombineJson(JSON_List):
      #Jsonlist should be a list of tuples, with the dictionary key and the json file to go with that.
      #eg: [('json1', 'some json string'), ('json2', 'some other json string')]
      Python_Dict = {}
      for tup in JSON_List:
            parsed_json = json.loads(tup[1])
            Python_Dict[tup[0]] = parsed_json
      BigJson = json.dumps(Python_Dict)
      return BigJson
```

Thanks guys,
Alex